# AJAX problem-onreadystate does not work

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having a problem where my AJAX code does not get past the onreadtstate. The if( XMLHttpRequestObject) works fine, but the other part does not. The code is below:

```
enter code here function 
//Get the Ajax Object
getXmlHttpRequestObject() { 

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest  && !(window.ActiveXObject)) {
    XMLHttpRequestObject= new XMLHttpRequest();
    return XMLHttpRequestObject;
 }
 else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
     try{
     XMLHttpRequestObject=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
     return XMLHttpRequestObject;
     }catch(exception1){

         try{
            XMLHttpRequestObject= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            return XMLHttpRequestObject;
         }catch(exception2){

         }//end exception 2
     }//end exception 1
 }//end if else
 else{
 document.getElementById('ajax_status').innerHTML='Status: Cound not create XmlHttpRequest Object.' +
'Consider upgrading your browser.';
 }
   }//end function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {

  function loadJavascript( src, url ){

XMLHttpRequestObject=getXmlHttpRequestObject();

if( XMLHttpRequestObject){
    //an alert will work here
    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        alert("Here");
                    //Nothing at this pint works    
        if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
            includeJavaScript( sId, url, oXmlHttp.responseText );
        }
    }

}
}//end LoadJavaScript
```

Does anyone have an idea of what can be going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You never send your request. The XMLHttpRequest doesn't do anything before you call `open()` and `send()` on it.

Also, don't forget to prefix your local variables with `var` when declaring them. Otherwise they'll be created as global and nasty things might happen.

Comment: @Matti is right. Also consider using a 3rd-party JavaScript library such as jQuery or Prototype. Writing browser-specific code is bygone, and these libraries will provide you with programming interface which is at best completely browser-independent.